# Quick Sort isn't working correctly with swapping function without temporary variable

Tags: swift, quicksort, swap

I have been working with sorting algorithm and I found out that quicksort doesn't work correctly with swap function without a temporary variable. I have attached the code below. You can execute this code in swift playground, its written in swift. [This is the link to execute this code online.](https://iswift.org/playground)
Please let me know any other info you require to sort this out. I would really appreciate if somebody can explain this.

Note - I have commented the two kinda code in swap functions. one without temporary variable and other is a temporary variable. This code perfectly works with swap function with a temporary variable.

```
func swap(_ a:inout Int , _ b:inout Int)
{

   a = a+b
   b = a-b
   a = a-b

   /*

   let x = a
   a = b
   b = x
  */
 }

 func partition(_ arr : inout [Int], _ low : Int, _ high : Int )->Int
 {
    let pivot = arr[high]
    var i = low-1
    var j = low
    while(j<high)
    {
       if(arr[j]<=pivot)
       {
          i=i+1
          swap(&arr[i],&arr[j])
       }

       j = j+1
    }
    swap(&arr[i+1],&arr[high])
    return i+1
 }
 func quickSort(_ arr : inout [Int], _ low : Int, _ high : Int )
 {
    if low < high
    {
       let pi = partition(&arr,low,high)
       quickSort(&arr,low,pi-1)
       quickSort(&arr,pi+1,high)
    }
 }

 var arr = [11 , 40 ,50 ,20 ,30,77,90,77,14,8,897,765,34,0,89]
 print(arr)
 quickSort(&arr,0,arr.count-1)
 print(arr)
```

Comment: My guess is that sometimes a and b point to the same element. Using "smart" algorithms was the pitfall of many programmers. Using temporary variable or even the swift native swap function would be better. Magic arithmetic swap has many problems. It would be even more dangerous on floating point values.

Comment: @Sulthan I don't think its something random cause output is same at every run . I believe this is somewhat related to loop and swap function. No?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "swap without temporary variable" does not work if both
arguments point to the same array element:

```
func swap(_ a:inout Int , _ b:inout Int) {
    a = a+b
    b = a-b
    a = a-b
}

var a = [5, 6, 7]
swap(&a[0], &a[0])
print(a) // [0, 6, 7]
```

Note that even passing two *different* elements of the *same array*
as inout argument to your function is undefined behavior.
In Swift 4/Xcode 9 you would get a compiler warning:

```
var a = [5, 6, 7]
swap(&a[0], &a[1])
// warning: overlapping accesses to 'a', but modification requires exclusive access; consider copying to a local variable
```

and a runtime error:

> Simultaneous accesses to 0x1005e4f00, but modification requires exclusive access.

That's why the `swapAt()` method (taking two *indices* as arguments)
was added to `MutableCollection` in Swift 4.

See [SE-0176 Enforce Exclusive Access to Memory](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0176-enforce-exclusive-access-to-memory.md) for more information.

Comment: Ah yes thats it. My mac needs some fixing , so was working on windows laptop and thats why i didn't get this warning. Just wanted to confirm that swap(&arr[i],&arr[j]) this code doesnt wok correctly when i == j !!! right martin?

Comment: I have basic experience with algos but i want to start fresh, can you recommend something intersting and knowledgeable book for algorithms ?

Comment: The classical swap without temporary uses XOR which does not have overflow problems but it would still fail when trying to swap the same element.

Comment: @va05: Even for different array indices it is undefined behavior (even if it works by chance)

Comment: @MartinR You mean to say this swapping without a temporary number isn't reliable way to accomplish swapping? And please some good book recommendation for algos

Comment: Both swapping methods are unsafe when applied to elements of the same array. It is explained in the link.

Answer (score 1):

Your swap function will break when `a` and `b` point to the same element. Prefer the version with a temporary variable which is more readable and works correctly for every data type and every value.

Note that the function can also overflow when adding two high values and it could completely break on floating point values.